# How to split apart a string in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can we do this in xaml using string format at all? I do not want to use any C# as I have no access to that.

For example:

```
<sap:Parameter x:Key="DescriptionForDisplay">
    <sap:Parameter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DescriptionConverter}" ConverterParameter="/">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource aDataSource}" Path="Properties[ID].Value"/>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource aDataSource}" Path="Properties[Description].Value"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </sap:Parameter.Value>
</sap:Parameter>
```

Would give something like:

```
1234\My Description
```

And I would love to do the inverse of this so I could have one parameter/static resource set as '1234' and another parameter/static resource be 'My Description'

Comment: `ConvertBack` method of the `DescriptionConverter` is not an option?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `StringFormat` like this:

```
<sap:Parameter x:Key="DescriptionForDisplay">
    <sap:Parameter.Value>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}\{1}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource aDataSource}" Path="Properties[ID].Value"/>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource aDataSource}" Path="Properties[Description].Value"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </sap:Parameter.Value>
</sap:Parameter>
```

This would display the Id\Description without the use of any converter.

Comment: How do I access these parameters though? I need to convert from the description with the dash, and put the two strings into separate parameters.

Comment: Why do you mean by "two separate parameters"? If you mean two different source properties you should define two different source properties.

Comment: I would need to separate them into two different properties from the single property defined by the '\'. I do not have access to the code behind.

Comment: XAML is a *markup* language. It cannot separate a string into two different properties so forget about doing this in XAML.